# Get user country based on ip-address without asking for permission on ios

Tags: ios, geolocation, ip-address

I'm developing an iOS app and one of the app features requires that I have information about the device current country.

I understand one of the possible solutions is using the CFLocation framework, but that service provides information too specific for my needs and requires prior consent from the user and can also be disabled.

So I'd like to know if I'm able to use other solutions such as a geolocation web service based on ip address without the need to ask for user prior consent. One example is this web service which would work perfectly for my needs: http://ip-api.com/

My only concern is regarding apple's approval. I've done a lot of research and found lots of information, but none of them confirmed me that.

Could I make a request to this webservice and get the current country based on the user's ip address without having to ask for user permission?

Moreover, if that is not possible, there is also the option to get the locale from the user and use that. Although that's not exactly what I need, because it doesn't return the user location and can be changed by the user at anytime. Does this option also need to ask for user permission?

To summarize, I need to get the user location but I can't ask for it and, most important, I have a short deadline and can't be rejected by apple. I know that is a tuff question because no one knows exactly Apple's criteria, but it would be great if anyone that faced the same problem could give his testimonial and help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do it.

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality) clearly state

> **4.1** Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected